# How to create a custom listview like this with react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ui-components

I am new to React Native development. I tried to recreate the below listview with react native and It failed. I just want to know if we can recreate below UI design with react native or the name of this listview type.

Thank You.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can recreate such component in `react-native`, however, it would be too complex to discuss it here. You can look into [react-native-snap-carousel](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel), which is the closest open-source library to your case that comes to mind.